# Check String is NULL or EMPTY

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hi I understand there are duplicates like ([Firebase Registration, Given String is empty or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345044/firebase-registration-given-string-is-empty-or-null)) and ([I keep getting"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null" and it has something to do with auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195593/i-keep-gettingjava-lang-illegalargumentexception-given-string-is-empty-or-null)).

Both articles mentioned solution about the api_key. I have checked mine and they were already exist so I strongly believe it is no longer due to that. As such I researched further and found out that I need to have something to check empty so I got these ([Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)) and ([Checking if a string is empty or null in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721397/checking-if-a-string-is-empty-or-null-in-java)).

I did tried their solutions but to no avail - I am still getting the above-mentioned error. I coded it using my instincts and the guides given but I am still not entirely sure if I did it right or not. As in, whether the mistakes are the codes itself or I placed them wrongly.

Can anyone help me to check and provide guidance so I can correct the mistake?
NOTE: I'm using Firebase for authentication.

Below are my codes:

```
package com.example.run_h.boav2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Username;
private EditText Password;
private TextView Info;
private Button Login;
private int counter = 3;
private Button userRegistration;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private TextView forgotPassword;

String name, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    userRegistration = (Button)         
    findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
    forgotPassword = 
    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvForgotPassword);

    Info.setText("# of Attempts Left: 3");


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //user has logged in and never once logged out. auto 
    bring to the secondactivity (dashboard) page.
    if(user != null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
    SecondActivity.class));
    }

    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validate(Username.getText().toString(), 
   Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    userRegistration.setOnClickListener(new 
   View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
   RegistrationActivity.class));
        }
    });

    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new 
   View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
   PasswordActivity.class ));
        }
    });
}

private void validate(String userName, String 
userPassword){

    progressDialog.setMessage("Please hold on. We are 
testing your patience!");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, 
 userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> 
 task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                checkEmailVerification();
            }
            else{
   //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login failed. 
   Incorrect username or password. Please try again.", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                checkEmptyCredentials();
                counter--;
                Info.setText("# of Attempts Left: " + counter);
                if(counter == 0){
                    Login.setEnabled(false);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PasswordActivity.class)); //forces user to reset password
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private Boolean checkEmptyCredentials(){
    Boolean result = false;

    name = Username.getText().toString();
    password = Password.getText().toString();

    if(name != null && name.isEmpty() || password != null && password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "All fields must not be blank.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}


private void checkEmailVerification(){
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Boolean emailflag = firebaseUser.isEmailVerified();

    if(emailflag){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please verify your email and account to login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
}
```

}

**Error trace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.run_h.boav2, PID: 27092
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.run_h.boav2.MainActivity.validate(MainActivity.java:89)
    at com.example.run_h.boav2.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:21)
    at com.example.run_h.boav2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: you might be getting the same error as in those links, but it would be helpful if you post your error trace here

Comment: @Kartik It is the same, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null" error

Comment: Please post your full error trace

Comment: @TruongHieu See updated post

Comment: @F4y5 any chance when you clicked submit while any field above is empty?

Comment: @TruongHieu Yes yes! My app crashed when I clicked "Login" button when the two edit text fields (Email & Password) are empty.

Comment: @F4y5 check my answer.

Comment: @F4y5 recently i change my wrong comment line. Just fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with `getText()`. You need to check the result of `getText()`, and not the subsequent `toString()`:

```
CharSequence text = someEditText.getText();
if (text == null) {
    //do what you do when the text is null or empty
}

String stringText = text.toString();
if (stringText.isEmpty()) {
    //do what you do when the text is null or empty
}
```

This is because, for whatever reason, if `getText()` is `null`, then `toString()` is called on the EditText instance itself, which will return the full classname of EditText and that instance's hashcode.

Also, you should be calling the result of `checkEmptyCredentials()` *before* you call `validate()`, not *after* you attempt the login. This is likely the cause of your crash, while the above will fix an error you haven't yet run into.

Comment: Thank you!! You are right, I should have moved the checkEmptyCredentials before validate. The solution is what I need as I don't have to make any further changes to the existing codes! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

`firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` function does not allow null or empty text. So you have to make sure that these fields are not null & not empty.

For easier check, i suggest you using this class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils. It has a function `isEmpty()` which can check null and empty in 1 call.

```
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) return; // userName null or empty. We do not process it.
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) return; // userPassword null or empty. We do not process it.

    progressDialog.setMessage("Please hold on. We are 
testing your patience!");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, 
 userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> 
 task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                checkEmailVerification();
            }
            else{
   //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login failed. 
   Incorrect username or password. Please try again.", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //checkEmptyCredentials();  //We need to check before signin. So you can replace my code lines above with this function.
                counter--;
                Info.setText("# of Attempts Left: " + counter);
                if(counter == 0){
                    Login.setEnabled(false);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PasswordActivity.class)); //forces user to reset password
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really useful! I have tried and they worked really well :) Although I can't accept yours as the solution as TheWanderer provided the solution before yours, I have upvoted it to be useful! Thank you for taking the time to read and understand through my problem thus providing solution to my error. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!password.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!email.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(name, password).addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                // there was an error
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Something Went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                checkEmailVerification();
            } }
    });

}

                    } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "All fields must not be blank.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```